# How to refresh tabhost inside a fragment?

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, android-tabhost

I have placed my tabhost inside a fragment. Tab host is having two tabs. I am using below code

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("TabA").setIndicator("TabA"),TabA.class, arg1);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("TabB").setIndicator("TabB"),
        TabB.class, arg1);
```

`TabA` and `TabB` are also fragments. How to refresh the nested fragment on tab change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the same with view page.